# How can i do decorator with and without parameters?

Tags: typescript

I want to do decorator that can use with and without parameters, for example :

```
@Controller
class SomeClass{
}

@Controller("some_arg")
class AnotherClass{
}
```

it is possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to typescript documentation:

> If you want your decorator to receive parameters then your decorator function needs to return the actual decorator function.

So you to create a decorator which handles two cases:

1. When you don't pass anything it should act as a normal decorator
2. When you pass a string, it should return a new decorator

You can also use [Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to have type safety.

So the final example would be:

```
function Controller(value: string): <T>(target: T) => T 
function Controller<T>(target: T): T 
function Controller<T>(value: string | T): T | ((target: T) => T)  {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return (target: T) => {
      // Value is string, target is class
      return target
    }
  }
  // Value is class
  return value
}

@Controller
class SomeClass{}

@Controller("some_arg")
class AnotherClass{}
```